# Operational error when writing to database in Raspberry Pi's Python

Tags: raspbian, python, rpi.gpio, sqlite

I'm having an operational error when trying to run IDLE program (Python) in Raspberry Pi and it prompt me an error sentences:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/www/Sensor-LED.py", line 34, in <module>
   Blink (int(iterations), float(speed))
 File "/var/www/Sensor-LED.py", line 15, in Blink
   curs.execute("INSERT INTO led values(timestamp('now'), (?)")
OperationalError: no such function: timestamp
```

I use SQLite 3 in Raspberry Pi to create my table and I only created 1 column which is timestamp only.

```
import sqlite3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## Use board pin numbering
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT) ## Setup GPIO Pin 7 to OUT

dbname='/var/www/ledDB.db'

##Define a function named Blink()
def Blink(numTimes, speed):
    conn=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    curs=conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO led values(timestamp('now'), (?))")

    for i in range(numTimes):## Run loop numTimes
        print "Iteration " + str(i + 1)## Print current loop
        GPIO.output(7, True)## Switch on pin 7
        time.sleep(speed)## Wait
        GPIO.output(7, False)## Switch off pin 7
        time.sleep(speed)## Wait
        #commit the changes
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
    print "Done" ## When loop is complete, print "Done"
    GPIO.cleanup()

## Ask user for total number of blinks and length of each blink
iterations = raw_input("Enter total number of times to blink: ")
speed = raw_input("Enter length of each blink(seconds): ")

## Start Blink() function. Convert user input from strings to numeric data types and
##pass to Blink() as parameters
Blink(int(iterations), float(speed))
```

Hope you guys could help me out with it as soon as possible.

Comment: `dbname='/var/www/ledDB.db'` sounds like a security issue.

Comment: That's a path to get my database, lenik

Comment: Your `for` block is out of blink function. I hope this is just of poor markup, because in this state your code won't work properly. This question is definitely about *<<General Python Usage>>* and you better ask it on **StackOverflow**

Comment: Lenik's probably referring to the location and the fact that it's not obfuscated/encrypted at all. Someone could look at your code and find out where you keep all the "top-secret secrets".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the SQL command switched up. The `(?)` should be within the `values([HERE])` and the `timestamp('now')` should be where the `(?)` is currently:

**Wrong**:

```
##Define a function named Blink()
def Blink(numTimes, speed):
    conn=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    curs=conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO led values(timestamp('now'), (?))")
```

<strike>**Correct**:</strike>

```
##Define a function named Blink()
def Blink(numTimes, speed):
    conn=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    curs=conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO led values(?)", (timestamp('now'),))
```

I believe this is what you need. As of right now, I believe your code is attempting to run the `timestamp('now')` function within SQLite, and I don't believe SQLite has that.

**EDIT**: My bad, you probably can't execute a command within a Python SQLite command/connection. This should fix it:

**Correct**

```
##Define a function named Blink()
def Blink(numTimes, speed):
    conn=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    curs=conn.cursor()
    timeNow = time.time()
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO led values(?)", (timeNow,))
```

I simply added the statement `timeNow = time.time()` and swapped out `timestamp('now')` for `timeNow`.

Comment: RPi Awesomeness, I now been prompted a new error and its NameError: global name 'timestamp' is not defined

Comment: @user3127380 this is not the place to learn general python programming, please, ask the question on stackoverflow.com

Comment: I did tried but they either ignore or hold the question, lenik

Comment: There is no `timestamp` function. Just replace `timestamp('now')` with `time.time()` and everything should work fine

Comment: Parameters are of unsupported type after following your step, oxfn

Comment: Thanks for your tips, RPi Awesomeness. I modify your method and it works for me.

Comment: Glad to help! It's always great when we resolve issues! I had problems exactly like yours when I was working on a project, so I knew exactly what to look for and how to fix it! :D